# Proposed canonical question regarding database subclasses

Tags: discussion, canonical

There is a question asked today that, I think,  would make a good canonical question for a question that has been asked, with different specifics, hundreds of times here in Stack Overflow.

The question is about database design for superclasses and subclasses, although the questioner doesn't use that terminology.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47865017/about-sql-performance) is the question.

It's about to be closed as "too broad".  And it is too broad.  But I think it would make a very good canonical question.  It needs to be reworded slightly.  It needs a good canonical answer.  My answer needs improvement to be a canonical answer,  but it's  a  start.  One improvement would be to get rid of the references to the three tags, which are fairly worthless tags anyway.

The third thing needed would be some way of guiding people with a question that is about designing database tables for subclasses to the canonical question and its answer.  We get at least a dozen such questions every week, and we could save ourselves and the questioners a whole lot of time and trouble if we could guide them to the right place.

### I've never been down this road before, so I really need your opinions and your help.  Are there reasons to discard this question as a canonical question?  Is it better to concoct a question to be self answered for this purpose?  And here's the big question:  how do you help people who have a specific question,  but don't recognize the canonical question as being related to their question?  Almost no one who asks a database and subclass question recognizes it as such.

Edit:

I have taken a shot at rewording the question, including the title.

I changed the title to make it more relevant to the question being asked.  I changed the body to include 3 illustrative examples.  The idea is to let the reader know what the question is really talking eabout.

These fixes may be inadequate or even counterproductive.  I just don't know.

I also changed my answer to make it look more like the answer I gave over at the DBA site.  This runs contrary to DRY.  it might be more productive for me to give one of thOse "may be answered here" comments.

**Edit:**

The question has been closed.  This discussion is now moot.  I'm not going to try to write my own canonical question.  I don't think I'm all that good at such a thing.  I'm going to try to start using the "This question may be answered here" comment.  See how that goes.  Others can vote to close, if they so choose.

Comment: Best thing you can do at this point (from what I can see) is clean up the question. It's pretty rambly, may not have high SEO for similar questions.  Also, the title sucks.  Clarify, generalize and rephrase to add honey to the pot.

Comment: Thanks.  I've reworded the title to make it about subclasses instead of performance.  But that's still problematic.  Subclasses is more object speak than database speak. Not sure how to rephrase the question.  I recognize the Q as the generic equivalent of dozens of specific questions I have answered in the past.  Meanwhile,, an anser I put up ver in DBA has been well received.  I'm not sure why.  More later.

Comment: I doubt if this question would be the go-to canonical question. It needs a lot of work. You might as well write the question yourself.

Comment: I may well go that way.  The problem with this question is that it is so generic that it is vague.  The problem with some other questions I have seen is that they ask about a particular case.  The case may be pets, which may include dogs, cats, and  goldfish.  Someone comes along later, trying to design for vehicles, which may include autos, trucks (lorries), and motorcycles.  The new person fails to see that it's the same problem that has already been answered.

Comment: Stop answering the questions and close vote them as duplicates. If you want a canonical question, write one that says, I suppose my situation could be described in these many ways, then bullets, then, I suppose my situation could be implemented these many ways, then bullets. (Including the antipattern of many FKs to many tables) Then in the answer explain that they are all cases of some things being kinds of other things. The subquestion re which design is "best" needs a link to a canonical question that "best" doesn't mean anything & a link to a canonical basic SQL optimization checklist.